# org.apache.http, org.apache.xerces

Tags: apache, http, import, classnotfound

So im trying to import

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

import org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.Entity
```

Non of these are found. I have a different project that is importing the exact same things and it works. But not on this project. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

```
---------------------------------------------------
tomcat              2.1.0            --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webxml              1.4.1            --  WebXmlConfig
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I got it. Thanks all of you that looked at this! I went through and reloaded all my dependencies one by one and it happened to work itself out.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem is usually that the libraries (xerces) are not imported, you can download it from [here.](http://archive.apache.org/dist/xml/xerces-j/Xerces-J-bin.1.4.4.tar.gz)

[Oficial web](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/api.html)

Cheers.